# How to use NetBeans to debug C++ libraries not compiled with NetBeans?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, netbeans, vtk

I am using NetBeans 6.8 on Redhat Linux.  Does anyone know how to configure NetBeans to debug (step into) libraries not compiled with NetBeans?

In my particular case, I'm trying to debug the VTK library which is built using cmake with the Debug flag set.  I've written a C++ application that uses the shared libraries from VTK.

Any ideas?  I'd tried the obvious things like adding the source locations to the project.

Note that with gdb I can debug the application and set breakpoints anywhere in VTK.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article on NetBeans 5.5 on how to integrate GDB into your project: http://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/articles/debugging/Review_NikMolchanov/NetBeansC_C++DevelopmentPack5.5_Debugging.html

I realize that you mentioned 6.8 but since there have been no other answers it might help point you in the right direction at least.